# Aggregated Query in elastic search is not returning output

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

```
This is my code snippet :

 if (aggfunction1=="sum")
                {



       var my_query="{\"size\": 0 ,\"query\": {\"bool\":
         {\"must\": {\"match\": { \""+ field1 +"\":\""+ value1 +"\"}}}},
         \"aggs\":{\"sum_fld\":{\"sum\": {\"field\":\""+ aggfield1 +"\"}}}}"

             console.log(my_query);
                client.count({
              index: 'paypal',
             body:my_query
},
 function (err, response) 
 {
    //countM = response.count;
     aggs= res.aggregations;

     console.log("\nAggregated Value is : " + aggs);
    res.send("\nAggregated Value is : " + aggs);
});
};
```

I am running this in nodejs and i am getting an error ?    I tried it in elasticsearch, but it is returning me documents ?
    **What I want :**
    Lets say I have a field SentMails. I want the average SentMails in the table where a field equals a value ?

Comment: Better if you can add the error you get as well

Comment: I am getting aggs is undefined. I tried accessing the output through sum)fld option also but it was not successful